# ¿Qué diferencias hay entre c() y append() a la hora de agregar un elemento a un vector?

Tags: r

En `R` si necesitamos agregar un elemento/vector a otro podemos hacerlo de dos formas:

```
mi_vector <- c(0,0,0)
mi_vector <- c(mi_vector, 1)
mi_vector
[1] 0 0 0 1

mi_vector <- c(0,0,0)
mi_vector <- append(mi_vector, 1)
mi_vector
[1] 0 0 0 1
```

¿Que diferencias hay entre `c()` y `append()`?, ¿Cuándo conviene usar una u otra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digamos que [`c()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) es una de las funciones más primitivas y simples de R, y sirve justamente para crear vectores, [`append()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/append.html) por el contrario es una función más compleja y una "envoltura" o "wrapper" alrededor de [`c()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) tal como podemos verificar viendo el código

```
function (x, values, after = length(x)) 
{
    lengx <- length(x)
    if (!after) 
        c(values, x)
    else if (after >= lengx) 
        c(x, values)
    else c(x[1L:after], values, x[(after + 1L):lengx])
}
```

[`append()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/append.html)  provee un mecanismo de inserción dentro del vector, más sencillo en algunos casos. Se puede decir que para operaciones básicas de concatenación, dónde el elemento nuevo lo queremos al principio o al final del vector, [`c()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) es la opción óptima, más simple de escribir, menos código ejecutado:

```
# Usando c()
mi_vector <- c(mi_vector, 1)  # Inserción al comienzo
mi_vector <- c(1, mi_vector)  # Inserción al final

# Usando append()
mi_vector <- append(mi_vector, 1, Inf) # Inserción al comienzo
mi_vector <- append(mi_vector, 1)      # inserción al final
```

Sin embargo, cuando lo que se busca es "insertar" un vector en una posición interna determinada [`append()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/append.html) sin duda hace diferencia:

```
mi_vector <- c(0,0,0)
mi_vector <- append(mi_vector, 1,  after = 2)
mi_vector

# Lo mismo pero usando c()
mi_vector <- c(0,0,0)
mi_vector <- c(mi_vector[1:2], 1, mi_vector[3:length(mi_vector)])
mi_vector
```

Vemos que el código es más compacto y menos susceptible a errores a la hora de definir los índices de recorte, como nos tocaría si usáramos [`c()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html).

fuente: [Difference between c() and append()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16144926/6836377)